# How to transfer Provisioning Profile from one team to another?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

When I view accounts in the Xcode, I saw 2 teams in my Apple ID account:

[image]

1. Where can I manage the team of my account such as delete, add and etc?
2. How can I transfer the provisioning profile from the Free personal team to the agent team?
3. How can I delete the provisioning profile in the Free team?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming you are an admin or user agent, go to developer.apple.com and log into the member center. On the very first screen click the "People" tab on the top left. That lets you manage the people on your team.
2. To the best of my knowledge you can't transfer provisioning profiles. They are signed using a specific developer's credentials. You'll need to create new ones under your paid developer account.
3. Again from the top level of the developer's member center, click on "Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles." from there click on profiles under iOS. If you select an individual profile there is a button at the bottom to delete it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question. I guess I am admin or user agent as I am create & paying the developer fee on my account. But why is that I can't see the "People" tab on my page? Btw, I am able to manage & delete provisioning profile in the agent team, which I can manage from the web login. But how can I delete provisioning profile in the FREE team? I can't find it in the webpage.

Comment: I don't know anything about Apple's new free developer accounts. I've never had one.